# Given $A$ a symmetric square matrix. Why is $f_A: O(n) \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}: Q \mapsto Q^{\top} A Q$ continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity

Given $A$ a symmetric square matrix. And $O(n)$ the set of orthogonal matrices. Why is the following function continuous:

$$f_A: O(n) \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}: Q \mapsto Q^{\top} A Q$$

This is part of a prove from a chapter of "Proofs from the Book". There is no comment on why this is true. But I puzzles how I could show this. In fact, I think I don't really understand what is meant with continuous here.

Similarly, somewhere else is mentioned that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} : Q \mapsto Q Q ^\top$ is continuous.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you prove: product of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: @GEdgar I have surely proved that a couple of years ago in a real analysis course. But with matrices, I get a bit confused to be honest.

Comment: Probably this proof is too advanced for you.

Comment: @GEdgar It is some time ago, since I studied this. But something things are coming back. Could/should I see it as a mapping $f_A: \Bbb R^{n\times n} \to \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ because then it makes more sense to me. With the euclidean metric.

Comment: Then every entry is a polynomial of $q_{11}, ... , q_{nn}$ and therefore continuous.

Comment: @Kasper I don't want to make it even more complex. However a good question to ask yourself is "how do you define continuity on the space $O(n)$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net First things that come to mind is that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open for every open subset $A$ of $O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is because matrix multiplication is continuous, and $Q\longmapsto Q^{-1}$ is continuous in $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbf R)$, and in the subgroup $\;\operatorname{O}(n)$, $\;Q^{-1}={}^{\mathrm t}Q$.

Comment: No need to mention inverse.  $Q \mapsto Q^{\top}$ is continuous.

Comment: I wanted to use the plain definition of a topological group. We also might say it's a quadratic function of the coefficients of the matrix.

Comment: In what kind of book could I learn about why matrix multiplication,  $Q\mapsto Q^{-1}$ is continuous, and $Q\mapsto Q^\top$ is continuous? I own Topology by James R. Munkres, would that be a good one? @GEdgar